# Pandas List Append Issue! Can Print() but Cannot .append()

Tags: python, loops, pandas, append

I am working on a small project and need to carryout some heavy data scrubbing. So far, so good but I have hit a brick wall.

I cannot append variables to a list. I can print them out, but when I attempt to .append() these variables, the first item only is successful.

```
for i in gr2.Segment.tolist():
    l = len(i[0])
    r = len(i[1])
    dl = []
    dl.append(l)
```

The code above does not work but if the last 4th and 5th lines are substituted with the following:

```
print(l,r)
```

The values I need appended to the list print out to the console.

Please advice. I have tried converting variables 'l' and 'r' to strings, that did not solve the issue.

I would like assistance on append the variables 'l' and 'r' to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
for i in gr2.Segment.tolist():
    l = len(i[0])
    r = len(i[1])
    dl = []
    dl.append(l)
```

with

```
dl = []
for i in gr2.Segment.tolist():
    l = len(i[0])
    r = len(i[1])
    dl.append(l)
```

You re-declare your list every iteration - that's why.

Comment: Thanks, I am running the command, but my cursor still blinking + 30secs